# Why is bitbucket not automatically updating my pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

After pushing to a branch that's the subject of a pull request, I'm getting the message

> There are new commits not included in this pull request. Update now.

Why am I getting this, rather than the pull request being automatically updated?

The only difference between this pull request and other ones I've made with bitbucket is that this one involved a merge conflict, which I've since resolved. Does that play a role?

I tried searching for the error message, and only came across [other](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/9333/pull-request-merge-fails-with-unexpected) people with the same [question](https://twitter.com/cyberspike/status/461682884420456448).

Comment: @Downvoter: What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the table, but in short it's because Bitbucket Web UI knows about changes in the repo stored on the bitbucket infrastructure due to the git hooks it installs.

In some cases these become corrupted and rage ensues.

I've found the easiest way to deal with this is close your PR and re-open a new one. :s

source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/pull-requests-not-reflecting-changes-pushed-to-remote-branch-779171762.html

Answer (score 0):

Try and make sure that:

- upstream is up-to-date (`git fetch upstream`, with `upstream` being a remote referencing the original repo)
- your PR branch is rebased on top of upstream/master (with potential merge conflict resolution)

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1319791/8943755/5dcdcae4-354a-11e5-9f82-915914fad4f7.png]

Then try a `git push --force`and see if the PR update takes place or not.

Comment: As a heads up, in my situation, there's only a single central repo, plus various developers' machines.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm PR means there is a fork involved, no?

Comment: @VonC no it does not.

Comment: @air 6 years later, I agree: It does not.